# Ubuntu doesn't save state after Suspend

Tags: dual-boot, suspend, windows-10, 17.04, sony

I have a laptop with dual boot mode (windows 10 and ubuntu 17.04), on Windows 10 sleep and hibernation working fine, on Ubuntu when I suspend, the state isn't saved, as well hibernation does not function properly.

now I just need to make Ubuntu save the state after I suspend it.

My laptop is Sony Vaio VPCEB1E9J

Comment: Your definition of 'suspend' seems different from mine. Perhaps you could edit your question to explain what's not being saved?

Comment: No applications that I left opened before suspending my system were opened after the system woke up.

Comment: Does your newly-awakened Ubuntu system ask for a password? Does waking up take a minute, or is waking up super-fast?

Comment: Yes, it does, as well the waking up takes more or less a minute. Even the grub menu shows up, and I have to choose a system.

Comment: Grub means your system is rebooting, not suspending. That's why your are losing your applications and work. Suspend works well on most hardware, but not all : Search for how to test your hardware. Some hardware manufacturers don't care about Linux compatibility, and won't release the data kernel developers need to make suspend and hibernate work on Linux. If that's the case for your hardware, there may or may not be a workaround.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I found the answer here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1556934

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1556934).

You just have to edit the `/etc/default/grub` file as root, for example:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line where it says:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change that to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_sleep=nonvs"
```

After that, save the file and close it.

Then, you have to tell GRUB to update to the new configuration. You can do that by entering:

```
sudo update-grub
```

After that, reboot and enjoy!